# 2D rotating on z axis according to Time.deltaTime not working properly

Tags: unity, c#

This is in 2D by the way.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Whirl : MonoBehaviour
{
    float turnSpeed = -0.5f;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

The object where this script is attached to is not working properly. I never experienced this bug, but the z rotation is staying in a 0.002 range, like it's trying to rotate, but it can't. Any idea to fix this bug?

And yes, fixedDeltaTime is not the problem, because I already tried regular deltaTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for some reason you can't use any variation of `Time.deltaTime`, and instead have to use `Time.time`.

Comment: Time.deltaTime and Time.fixedDeltaTime represent the number of seconds between *consecutive* frames or physics steps, respectively — not the total time since game start or scene load. Time.fixedDeltaTime in particular is a constant of 0.02 unless you change it in the editor or set it in code, so it is never a sensible source to query when you want a value that increases over time.